# Looking for an algorithm to allocate climbing hold colors to wall sectors

Tags: algorithm, resources, allocation

I was not sure which SE site to pick - stackoverflow and math were the candidates - but as we might write a piece of software for this problem I decided to post it here.

In our climbing gym, we're facing the problem that adjacent wall sectors may not use equal (or similar) climbing hold colors. I'm looking for an algorithm for allocating climbing hold colors to wall sectors. Until now we did that manually, with varying and sometimes unpleasant results. Here are our "rules":

If a route in sector A is red, no red route may be set in the sectors nearby (A-1 and A+1). Preferably, no route with that color should be set in the sectors A-2 and A+2 unless special care is taken by the route setters to make the routes not "touch".

Different colors in one or adjacent sectors should be "sufficiently different". For example, combinations like red and pink are not allowed, red and violet should be avoided. Colors being complementary to each other is not really a reason to combine them in an area, because we have climbers who are red-green color blind (some other flavors as well). Also, there are non-colors such as white and black (also don't go together), fluorescent colors and holds with two or three colors combined. However, we can safely say which color combinations go well together, which should be avoided and which are not allowed.

There can be up to four routes in a sector. Sectors with just one or two routes should be avoided. We have different amounts of each color, so that must be taken into account as well. Sectors may be circular (such as around a pillar) or otherwise interconnected (a pillar and a nearby wall which are connected by a roof).

Is there a common approach to such a problem?

---

Edit 1:
I have implemented mbeckish's suggestion and wrote a simulated annealing algorithm for this problem. While I believe that my code works as it should, the results are not satisfactory.

Here are some details:

- There are 15 sectors with 4 routes each;
- There are 10 route colors: 3 primary, 3 secondary, black, white, turquoise and violet/white (combined);
- The amount of each color is fixed between 3 and 8 routes per color;
- The colors are "clustered" when the algorithm starts;
- I defined a matrix with a penalty (1e-2...1) for each possible color combination;
- the energy() function sums up all penalties within each sector and between adjacent sectors;
- the neighbour() function swaps a randomly chosen pair of routes between two different sectors (unless the route colors are equal, in that case a new pair for swapping is chosen);
- T() decays exponentially
- P() is implemented as in the [wikipedia article on simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

This will happily run and swap around, but the results always contain sectors with two routes of equal color. Nevertheless I'd like to include a "convergence" plot of energy (normalized; blue: current, green: best) vs iteration:

[image]

Results are similar when I shuffle the routes before starting the algorithm. It's like doing some pre-iterations without looking at penalties. Here is the same kind of plot, pre-shuffled, with a  faster decay of T() to make the algorithm more greedy, and more iterations:

[image]

---

Edit 2:
The neighbour() function now picks a random color (C1) from the sector with the highest energy (S1) and swaps it with a random color (C2) from a random other sector (S2), unless C1 is already contained in S2 or C2 is already contained in S1. This gives slightly better results, but they still contain sectors with duplicate colors. I'll try to come up with something different now.

Comment: I think [Stochastic Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization) would be a good approach to this problem, like simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm.

Comment: The article on simulated annealing is quite clear about what I need to define. While I can more or less intuitively define state space and objective function, the neighbour(), acceptance probability() and temperature() functions seem to be harder. And the "initial temperature" is an interesting thing in this context as well.

Comment: Even if you don't follow the definition exactly, you can use the basic ideas.  You need a way to score solutions.  Start by making large random changes to the solutions (so that you can jump out of local minima and have a better chance to find drastically improved solutions).  Over time, work your way towards smaller and smaller random changes (by now, you should have found a pretty good solution, and you don't want to jump away from it and get stuck working on a worse solution).  Near the end, you're just doing very minor tweaks to try to eke out a slightly better solution.

Comment: Yup, you're probably right about that. I think I'll just give it a try. Regarding your second suggestion (genetic algorithm): Creating a recombination algorithm seems to be hard, but on the other hand the outcome of that might be more sensible than a random neighbour in simulated annealing.

Comment: @mbeckish This is fun and frustrating at the same time. I've implemented SA for this problem, but it seems that my neighbour() function is not that good. I'll post more later when I've made some more experiences with this...